# How do I re-initialize values in a function resides in document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html file that has following code,

```
<div id="pp-photo-wrap">
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]">

     //Added this to debug
    <input id="debug" type="button" value="Print Design" onclick="alert(globalVars.selectedDesignId)" />
    <script>
    $j(document).ready(function(){
            $j('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'productpage/uploadphoto?design='+ globalVars.selectedDesignId,
                done: function (e, data) {
                    enablephotostudio(data);
                }           
            });
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

and I have another JS file with the following function that does heaps of stuff and among those it does the following,

```
function clickDesignItem(item_el) {
      ...
      ...
      globalVars.selectedDesignId = item_el.data('design_id');
      ...
      ...
 }
```

So my problem is I want to pass current `globalVars.selectedDesignId` in to `fileupload()` function along with the URL. but it always give me the design ID which the one it had when the document is loading.

But if I click on the "Print Design" button which I added to see weather `globalVars.selectedDesignId` has the correct value at the time `fileupload()` is calling, give me the current correct design ID.

So how do I reload the `document.ready` or pass the `globalVars.selectedDesignId` with the updated value?

Need help badly...

Comment: why don't you call `fileupload` inside the `clickDesignItem(item_el)` after the var is set ??

Comment: Oh I tried that and it worked. But I dont understand how that could work. Because they are 2 separate events. Can you please explain this to me as an answer. So I really understands the world of javascripts/Jquery :)

Comment: Isn't that when I put this inside the clickDesignItem(item_el), fileupload get calls each and every time even without files uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Basically users will select a design,`

so that means (i am guessing) `clickDesignItem` .. function is called first, where `globalVars` is defined , calling fileupload function after that will get the  `globalVars` as it should...

but here, you are calling the `fileupload` inside `document.ready()`.that means fileupload is called as soon as the document gets ready thus your `globalVars` might not be set till then....

Comment: Yep now I get that, But the part that I dont understand is, when I put fileupload() function within the clickDesignItem function,  each time when a user clicks on a design fileupload() is also get called without users not uploading anything isnt it?